# Stripcharts with same x-axis in R

Tags: r, charts, strip

I want to make a strip chart for each of the following two vectors with same x-axis using R.
Two vectors are:
x <- c(40,35,30,45,35,45,65,65,70,70)
y <- c(45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,95)

When I made strip charts for the two, it came out like this:

[image]

How do I make it so that two x-axis will be the same?

Thank you

Comment: Can you share the code you used for the plot?

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
It was:

x <- c(40,35,30,45,35,45,65,65,70,70) 
y <- c(45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,95)
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
stripchart(x,pch=1,method="jitter")
stripchart(y,pch=1,method="jitter")

Answer (score 0):

> How do I make it so that two x-axis will be the same?

The [`stripchart()` function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.5.1/topics/stripchart) takes an optional `xlim` parameter that lets you define the horizontal plot limits. For example:

```
x <- c(40,35,30,45,35,45,65,65,70,70)
y <- c(45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,45,95)
par(bty="n", mfrow=c(2,1), mar=c(2,1,3,1)+0.1)
stripchart(x, xlim=c(20,100), method="stack", pch=16)
stripchart(y, xlim=c(20,100), method="stack", pch=21)
```

[image: sample plot]

Comment: Thank you so much!
I really appreciate your help!!